# Formatting Section in KOMA-Script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I am using KOMA-Script (`scrartcl`). I am trying to figure out how can I achieve the section formatting similar to this figure.

[image: Section Style]

I found a CV example using `res` class ([CV using `res` class](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-graduate-cv)), but I want to use it in another document which uses `scrartcl`.

Comment: Do you have a question? Is something not working? If so, please show us the code you have (not all of it: a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) and explain what you are stuck on!

Comment: I was trying to modify the res.cls class to achieve the section formatting. I wanted to know which packages I should try to achieve the formatting. I will update the question with a short working example if I can.

Comment: You should work with the facilities Koma-Script offers if you are using `scrartcl`.

Comment: The maintainer of KOMA-Script has posted a solution: http://www.komascript.de/node/1866

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) makes for easy adjustment within a regular list (`description`) environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=7em, labelwidth=7em, labelsep=0pt]
  \item[OBJECTIVE]
  A position in the field of computers with special interests in business applications
  programming, information processing, and management systems.

  \item[EDUCATION]
  \textsl{Bachelor of Science}, Interdisciplinary Science \\
  Rensselaer Polytechnic Institude, Troy, NY, expected December 1990 \\
  Concentration: Computer Science \\
  Minor: Management  
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

As @cfr mentioned in a comment, KOMA-Script can do stuff pretty good on its own. Here an example using `labeling`. You can change the font of the labeling label using the `\addtokomafont` mechanism. The indent is taken by the length of the argument of the `labeling` environment. [Markus Kohm suggests some further improvements](http://www.komascript.de/node/1866), like putting the `\MakeUppercase` to a global place. This is nice, since you can change it add one place. Please have a look at the modified example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand*{\UpperCaseLS}[1]{\textls{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\addtokomafont{labelinglabel}{\sffamily\bfseries\UpperCaseLS}
\begin{document}
\begin{labeling}[\enskip]{education}
\item[objective] A position in the field of computers with special interests
  in business applications programming, information processing, and management
  systems.
\item[education]\raggedright
  \textsl{Bachelor of Science}, Interdisciplinary Science \\
  Rensselaer Polytechnic Institude, Troy, NY, expected December
  1990 \\
  Concentration: Computer Science \\ 
  Minor: Management
\end{labeling}
\end{document}
```

[image: maxKomaLabelingExt]

Little hint: Don't use uppercase, sans serif *and* bold face.